# Change TimeZone of CreatedDate

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime, timezone, outputtext

I am having some trouble finding detailed information on the 'z' value in the `<apex:outputText value="{0,time, hh:mm a z}">`

I have to display the timezone as `PST` and the z is only displaying `GMT`

I typically just use an apex method to change the format of the timezone but can't do that this time for a couple of reasons. (I can add these reasons in if you feel necessary). So what I am looking for is a way to manipulate the `<apex:outputText>` tag. Is this possible without apex? I imagine it is something along the lines of:

```
        <apex:repeat value="{!keysComment}" var="key">
            <th colspan="5" id="casenumber">{!key}</th>
            <apex:repeat value="{!dateHeaderComments[key]}" var="td">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,time, hh:mm a z, 'America/Los_Angeles'}">
                            <apex:param value="{!td.commentData.CreatedDate}" />
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
```

Resources that were semi helpful:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm#apex_methods_system_timezone

https://paulforce.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/formatting-time-in-apex/

Comment: have you read the date formatting example from the [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)?

Comment: what is your org's timeZone?

Comment: @Manjot Singh --> "I have to display the timezone as PST"

Comment: @glls I have. And from what I understand the z value can be either z, Z, or -z. And the z value can be either GMT or PST. But I am not sure how to get it to be PST.

Comment: I just stumbled across this article which might be helpful...I haven't tried it out yet. http://www.ultrageek.com/?p=169

Comment: I need to force the timezone to always be PST and I can't convert the time into a string.

Comment: @Olivia I don't think there is a way to do so in VisualForce. You will need to handle this in apex side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly hacky way of going about it but this article worked for me:
http://www.ultrageek.com/?p=169

I was able to offset the timezone by how ever many hours different I am from GMT time. So my outputText tag looks like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,time, hh:mm a}">
    <apex:param value="{!td.commentData.CreatedDate -7/24}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

This enables me to change the timezone without having to convert the DateTime into a string.

According to the documentation you get the -0.29 value by taking your GMT date/time field and divide one(1) by the number of hours offset. 1/4 = .166~ and 1/5 = .2 respectfully. This is obviously incorrect (the time difference between GMT and PST is 7 hours and 1/7 != 0.29) but what you can do is take the time difference and divide it by 24. ie: -7/24.

Comment: thx for sharing your solution :thumbsup:

Comment: So all of your user base has the same time zone offset?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes, I want everyone on PST

Comment: Ok. For orgs with multiple time zones a different approach would be needed. Also, you might want to explain where `0.29` came from. Magic numbers should be avoided where possible. :) IMO it would be better to do `... - 7/24`. Also note that this approach will *not* factor in Daylight Savings.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for the suggestion. I think that is better too. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting the the date in addition to the time you can massage it a bit to take into account the active users timezone. The nice thing about this is that it will also adjust for daylight savings.

Instead of this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,time, hh:mm a z}">
    <apex:param value="{!td.commentData.CreatedDate}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

You would do this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0}">
    <apex:param value=" {!td.commentData.CreatedDate}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Or just:

```
<apex:outputText value=" {!td.commentData.CreatedDate}" />
```

Note the extra space at the start of the param value.

Why does this work? I suspect the param is now being treated as a string rather than a Date or Time type. As a result, it is getting converted into the current users timezone (as is standard most other places in Visualforce).

You do lose the ability to specify the outputText format, as it will complain with:

> The value attribute on  is not in a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.